# Showing an interval $(a,b)$ is open.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, algebra-precalculus, algebraic-topology

I have come across an example where it  shows that given any interval $(a,b)$, for $a \lt b$, is open in $\mathbb{R}$.

The following is the stated solution:

$(a,b)$ Is open since given any $x \in (a,b)$, we can take $ \epsilon = min\{ |x-a|, |x-b| \}$ so that $ (x- \epsilon, x+ \epsilon ) \subseteq (a,b)$. $\qquad \blacksquare$

What I don't understand is that if $\epsilon$ is defined in this way, wouldn't the interval $(x- \epsilon, x+ \epsilon )$ include either $a$ or $b$, since if $x$ was chosen to be closer to $a$ than $b$ then $\epsilon=|x-a|$ which means that $x- \epsilon =a$, and so the final statement $(x- \epsilon, x+ \epsilon ) \subseteq (a,b)$ would be incorrect?

Would it not be more appropriate to define $\epsilon$ as $ \epsilon = min\{ \frac{|x-a|}{2}, \frac{|x-b|}{2} \}$, for example?

Comment: $y\in (x-\epsilon ,x+\epsilon )$ means $|y-x| < \epsilon$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)$ does not include $a$ or $b$. For example, take a look at what happens if $|x-a|<|x-b|$ (in which case $\epsilon = |x-a|$, and since $x>a$, you have $\epsilon = x-a$).

Then, the interval $$(x-|x-a|, x+|x-a|) = (x-(x-a),x+(x-a)) = (x-x+a,x+x-a)=(a,2x-a)$$

which is the set of all numbers **larger than** $a$ and smaller than $(2x-a)$.

---

In other words, $x-\epsilon=a$, sure, but $x-\epsilon\notin (x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)$ (just like $a\notin (a,b)$), so $a\notin(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$.

Comment: Ahh, I understand, thanks!

Comment: @Gurjinder Once you get an answer you like, you should also consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

If $\varepsilon = |x-a|$ then, since $x > a$, you get $x-a = \varepsilon $, so $x-\varepsilon = a$. Further $b-x > x-a = \varepsilon$, so $x+\varepsilon < b$. That means $(x-\varepsilon, x+\varepsilon) \subset (a,b)$. Similarly for in case $\varepsilon = |x-b|$. The point is that when you take $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)$ you don't include the boundary points, which means that you don't include $x-\varepsilon = a$. Similarly for the other cases.